# Jquery .siblings( ) mistake that i can't figure out

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi can you see what I am doing wrong with the jquery?
I am trying to make that when you hover over one of the texts the other two the css will be applied to. The error is to do with the $(".yo") or the ('blur'); I am linking them wrong ?
Thanks in advance

I have edited the jquery but now on mouseout it stays with the css on?!

**Jquery:**

```
$(".blur").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().addClass('blur textshadow');     }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('textshadow out');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="yo">
<div class="blur out" id="one"> hi </div>
<div class="blur out" id="two"> my </div>
<div class="blur out" id="three"> name </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.blur
{
text-decoration: none;
color: #339;
}

div.blur:hover, div.blur:focus
{
text-decoration: underline;
color: #933;
}

.textshadow div.blur, .textshadow div.blur:hover, .textshadow div.blur:focus
{
text-decoration: none;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
outline: 0 none;
-webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
-moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
transition: 400ms ease 100ms;
}

.textshadow div.blur,
.textshadow div.blur.out:hover, .textshadow div.blur.out:focus
{
text-shadow: 0 0 4px #339;
}

.textshadow div.blur.out,
.textshadow div.blur:hover, .textshadow div.blur:focus
{
text-shadow: 0 0 0 #339;
}
```

Comment: The `a.blur` elements are not siblings of `a.yo`; they are children. Siblings share a parent.

Comment: Cheers. Do you know how to make them siblings?

Comment: You'd have to change your HTML. Or do you just mean to use `.children()`?

Comment: What do you change the HTML to? :)

Comment: `<a>` elements can't be nested. It's invalid mark-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify it to this -

```
$('.blur').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).siblings().addClass('out textshadow');
},  function() {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('out textshadow');
});
```

Modify your CSS to this -

```
.blur { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #339; }  
div.blur:hover, div.blur:focus {
    text-decoration: underline; 
    color: #933; }  
.textshadow { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    outline: 0 none; 
    -webkit-transition: 400ms ease 100ms; 
    -moz-transition: 400ms ease 100ms; 
    transition: 400ms ease 100ms; }  
.out {
    text-shadow: 0 0 4px #339;}
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/r2gQ3/

BTW - it would be better to use another name for the blur class so that it doesn't get confused with the .blur() method.

Comment: the steps I want to happen:
1)normal css (.blur)
2)**mouse over** other css is applied (.out and.textshadow) to sibllings
3)**mouse out** back to part 1

Comment: I have made changes to the jQuery I listed. All you have to do is declare the CSS for blur and textshadow. Of course you can do all of this in CSS without using jQuery at all.

Comment: it now just makes the whole thing use the css. Thanks for your help! How could you do this just using css?

-------$(".blur").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).siblings().addClass('blur textshadow');     }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('textshadow out');
    }); 
-------
This is the closest i have got to what i want but here on mouse out it still leaves everything blurry!

Comment: I think your jquery is right but it is the layout of the css and which bit does what?

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea why but when text loads it has a glow behind it? other than that perfect!

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be the case. Make sure to accept this answer if it works for you.

Comment: Take the out class away from your markup - you have class="blur out" and it should be class="blur" like it is in the jsfiddle example.

Comment: Hi, sorry to keep bugging you. Currently on mouse out it goes immediately back to the beginning and doesn't smoothly go back. Any ideas?

Comment: It goes back immediately because there is not transition for the blur. Check this out and notice the changed CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/r2gQ3/1/

Comment: One last question! :) I should have mentioned this at the beginning but if you were to link it with an <a> tag how would i go about changing the css at the moment it is invisible untill you hover over [have a look here](http://tragicclothing.co.uk/del.html) Thankyou

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand, can you explain exactly what should happen when a hover occurs?

Comment: On the link it starts invisible and ends invisible it is somehow missing a bit of css and I am not sure where?

Answer (score 2):

`.blur` are children - fetch them with [`$(this).children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

```
<a class="yo">
    <a class="blur out" id="one"> hi </a>
    <a class="blur out" id="two"> my </a>
    <a class="blur out" id="three"> name </a>
</a>
```

That said, you **shouldn't** nest `<a>` tags. Are you sure you didn't mean to use a `div` tag?

---

`.blur` are siblings - fetch them with [`$(this).siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

```
<a class="yo">whatever</a>
<a class="blur out" id="one"> hi </a>
<a class="blur out" id="two"> my </a>
<a class="blur out" id="three"> name </a>
```

Comment: Your fist example is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Ok you definitly got a problem with the siblings function.
You use the "yo" class as a selector and when ask for its siblings. It has no siblings!
You need to get its children since all the other links are children of "yo".

Since i havent actually tested your code it hard to tell if you have other problems.
But it also seems wird to me to have 3 links inside a link ? whats the point? why isnt it 3 links inside a div ?

I hope this is a help

Regards Christen

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$(".yo").mouseover(function(){
```

to

```
$(".yo > div").mouseover(function(){
```

Ej:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".yo > div").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).siblings().addClass('blur');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('blur');
    }); 
});
```

Test: http://jsbin.com/ajokok/1/edit

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. in mine or the jsbin example.

Comment: Well it kind of works! if you look at "hi my name" the just seem to change color I want it to look like you have just put your mouse over "is"